# Mouse Pointer With a Square with text UBUNTU Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: screen, cursor, mouse-pointer

I had an automatic update and a square is chasing the cursor. It's seems to be some text really small.
Please check as follow a screen capture:
[image][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gndg.jpg

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com). Please refer to this [article](https://askubuntu.com/how-to-ask) so more people can answer your question better.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: Yes sure, here it's https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gndg.jpg
Thanks in advance for your help.